# Create sortables at runtime?

Tags: jquery-ui

How do we handle connect draggable items that should be connected to sortables when the sortables are created at run time? For example:

```
<ul class='sortable'>
</ul>
```

I create instances of the above sortable ul when the user clicks a button:

```
function onBtnClick1() {
    var element = $("<ul class='sortable'></ul>");
    element.appendTo("#body");
    $(".sortable").sortable();  // make it sortable?
}
```

Later on the user can generate items to drag and drop into any of the sortables:

```
function onBtnClick2() {
    var element = $("<span>Hi there</span>");
    element.draggable();
    element.draggable("option", "connectToSortable", '.sortable');
}
```

it isn't working though - I basically want to make the draggables above droppable into any ul that has the class type "sortable". What's the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should set two more option to draggable to make it work

```
element.draggable("option", "helper", 'clone');
element.draggable("option", "revert", 'invalid');
```

see documentation for [connectToSortable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable#option-connectToSortable) and [sortable draggable demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable)

the complete function should look like this

```
function onBtnClick2() {
    var element = $("<span>Hi there</span>");
    element.draggable({
        connectToSortable: '.sortable',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: 'invalid',
        appendTo: '#container'
    });
}
```